# routerlinkactive not working for angular 4 home button

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 navbar home,contact and product. `routerlinkactive` is working fine for contact and product link,but home link is always active why?

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

navbar.component.html

```
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/contact-us" >Contact-us</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/product" >Products</a></li>
```

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
      {path:'contact-us', component:ContactusComponent},
      {path:'product', component:ProductsComponent},
      {path:'**', component:NotfoundComponent}
    ])
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
```

Otherwise it will match all paths beginning with /

Comment: Thanks bro its working can u please share how its work?

Comment: It applies configuration to the routerLinkActive directive so that it will only apply if the paths match exactly. More info in the documentation if you're interested https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description